# Passing changing variables to RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a custom `RecyclerView.Adapter` that is used to render the layout of my list. In the parent Activity I have two variables that can be changed from the UI. These parameters are used to render part of the RecyclerView item.

I know I can pass some data via the Adapter constructor, but this is a one time thing. How can I pass data to the Adapter and change it on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your adapter implement a custom interface, define methods there for passing/getting data.

Comment: Great, this was a nice and simple solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### Best approach

Use `DataBinding`. With `DataBinding` you can mark fields in your class as `@Bindable` and then call `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.field_name)` to update diplaying of just that property. 
Here is little tutorial:

```
class Test extends BaseObservable{
@Bindable
String testString;

...

    public void setTestString(String newStr){
        this.testString = newStr;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.testString);
    }
...
}
```

And in your layout

```
<layout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<data>
    <variable
        name="test"
        type="com.yout.package.name.Test"/>
</data>
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@{test.testString}"/>
</FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

By this way you can simply go through your `List` of `Test` objects and call `setTestString` to update all views (only related `TextView` will be updated). 
[Here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) is guide to how to begin with DataBinding

### Decent approach

In your `RecyclerView.Adapter` you have method `notifyItemChanged(int position, Object payload)`. Just call this method and pass your update as `payload` parameter. And then there is an `onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position, List<Object> payloads)` where you'll can update your view.

Answer (score 1):

You can always add any public methods you want to your adapter and call them directly. You can either save a reference to your adapter in your `Activity` or cast the result of `recyclerView.getAdapter()`:

```
mAdapter = new YourAdapter();
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
...
mAdapter.yourCustomMethod(data);
```

or

```
YourAdapter adapter = (YourAdapter) recyclerView.getAdapter();
...
adapter.yourCustomMethod(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's when you use RecyclerView.Adapter's notifyDataSetChanged() method (as described [here in the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())) to **instantly** update the data in the RecyclerView via your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your adapter you can add a method like this:

```
public void setPropX(yourType propxVal){
    mPropX = propXVal; //Set the value of you property
    notifyDataSetChanged(); //Redraw all the elements
}
```

In your activity store a global reference of the adapter then call the function above when needed